# Can i create new adMob account with the old account email which has been disabled

Tags: android, admob, adsense

yesterday my adMob account has been disabled and i dont know why this has been disabled. since it was not generating much revenue so i didn't take it as frustrating. now i want to create a new account but i dont know whether i can create new admob account using the old account email which has been disabled yerterday. if yes then thanks to the admob for providing this facility. if no, then is it possible that my developer account and admob account emails are different in process of creation.

Answer (score 1):

You should have received a notification as to why your admob
account is disabled.

I believe you can appeal your "disabled" status. My understanding is
that the challenge is in actually getting in touch with them :)

I'm guessing that doing an end run around them with a new account will just
cause you more problems down the line.

Comment: yes i have received an email and they have written that i have done some invalid activity. also have submitted a form for appeal. but i want to know whether can i create a new account with the same email address i have used in the old one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create an admob account using your old disabled email address. Even if you try with a newly created email id to create a new account. It will also get disabled after a few days use